# Add element to a private Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm having trouble adding a new element to a ArrayList from another class.

This class is where the ArrayList is:

```
public class Registry {
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void addNum(int num) {
        this.nums.add(num);
    }
}
```

But when I call from another class, like this:

```
Registry reg = new Registry();
reg.addNum(1);
```

It doesn't add the `num` to the reg.nums..

Comment: How do you know? `nums` is `private` and you have no accessor.

Comment: Does `Registry` have a method to get the Arraylist?

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: What error did you see? I just tried your example and it worked as expected.

Comment: I appreciate that you've tried to prune down the example for clarity, but I think you went a little too far. From what we can see, this should work. Maybe show us how you're accessing the array, to tell that nothing's getting added?

Comment: This got an upvote. Now I have seen it all.

Comment: @Gendarme You have not been here long then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a *public accessor function* for a private object for a public class meets all requirements of object **encapsulation** and I don't see any reasons why you should not be able to access such objects.

I am not sure how you are checking the results. Hence thinking of giving an example to check whether it is working or not.

**Registry Class**

```
public class Registry {
    private ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public void addNum(int num) {
        this.nums.add(num);
        System.out.println("Size of array: " + this.nums.size());

        for (int n: nums){
            System.out.println("Element of the array: " + n);
        }
    }
}
```

**Test Class:**

```
public class TestArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args){


        Registry reg = new Registry();
        reg.addNum(11);
        reg.addNum(22);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

Size of array: 1
Element of the array: 11
Size of array: 2
Element of the array: 11
Element of the array: 22